# Dart - Binding between two objects

Tags: dart, data-binding, binding

Is there is an option somehow to bind two objects with Dart?
Two-way binding and or one-way binding?
Like JavaFX binding packages or some other systems.

Comment: Just want to be sure. What do you mean by "binding"?

Comment: Value of one object will update the second object automatically

Comment: If you mean if there are any language construct in Dart so you can get a subscription for updates on any fields of a given object then the answer is no.